# Why is field value not displaying for first record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following code that should show the value for the display field in my view:

```
<% @product.options.each do |o| %>
<tr>
    <td class="option"> 
    <%= o.display %> 
    ...
```

But the `o.display` part doesn't work for the very first option record.  On all other options, it correctly prints the display value, but not on the very first one.  I have verified in MySQL that a value exists for that particular option (Option 1):

```
mysql> select id,title,display from options;
+----+-----------------------------+---------+
| id | title                       | display |
+----+-----------------------------+---------+
|  1 | Option 1                    |       1 |
|  2 | Option 2                    |       2 |
|  3 | Option 3                    |       3 |
+----+-----------------------------+---------+
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**More info:**

If I add:

```
<%= debug o %>
```

before trying to print the display field, it not only shows debug information, but shows the display value properly.  With no debugging, it won't show the display value.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong; are you *sure* the product-in-question's options are what you think you are? That it works for every option except one points more towards a data/retrieval issue.

Comment: All other fields are displayed properly for the first option.  The data for the display field is showing on the other options.  Not sure how else I could verify anything else about the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[display](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/display) is a method of the Object class in Ruby and this created a problem with ActiveRecord I guess. Maybe you could change the name of that field, it should be the simpler option.

Comment: Is there another way to access the display field?  I find it odd that if this is a conflict with the Ruby method, that the other options will show the display field.

Comment: @croceldon Mmm, but the method might be added dynamically, although it still doesn't explain (to me) what's happening yet.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in the debugger and step thru.

I would put a debugger in the controller where @product (or whereever this and other instance variables are being set).

To put your rails app in a debugger - You need to add "gem ruby-debug" in your Gemfile and do bundle install. (you might need to do "ruby-debug19" if you're using ruby 1.9). When you hit the action, a console will popup where you've started the server. You can use "n" for next, "l" for list and "p" to print out objects. (Read the debugger manual).

You need to ask yourself "what is in @product.option"? Is it an array? Does it respond to each? What is the first element?

I would go as far as to remove the loop and just use "@product.option[0].display" in the option.

In absence of more information, the best i can help is to help you debug.